# How to position this tikz figure in the center of a A4paper?

Tags: formatting, tikz-trees

```
% Mindmap  
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz  
% https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook  
\documentclass[border = 100pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}  
%\usepackage[margin=9cm,showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}  
\usepackage{metalogo}  
\usepackage{dtklogos}  
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}  
  \path [  
    mindmap,  
    text = white, align=flush center,  
    level 1 concept/.append style =  
      {font=\large\bfseries, sibling angle=90},
    level 2 concept/.append style =
      {font=\normalsize\bfseries, level distance = 3.5cm, sibling angle=55},
    level 3 concept/.append style =  
      {font=\small\bfseries, level distance = 3.5cm, sibling angle=60},  
    tex/.style     = {concept, ball color=black,  
      font=\huge\bfseries},  
    engines/.style = {concept, ball color=green!50!black},  
    formats/.style = {concept, ball color=blue!50!black},  
    systems/.style = {concept, ball color=red!80!black},  
    editors/.style = {concept, ball color=orange!90!black}  
  ]  
  node [tex] {Samples} [clockwise from=0]  
    child[concept color=green!50!black, nodes={engines}] {  
      node {Mixtures} [clockwise from=750]  
        child { node {Series 1}}  
        child { node {Series 2} }  
       % child { node {\XeTeX} }  
        %child { node {Lua\TeX} }  
}  
    child [concept color=blue, nodes={formats}] {  
      node {Case Types} [clockwise from=300]  
        child { node {\LaTeX} }  
        child { node {Con\TeX t} }}  
    child [concept color=red, nodes={systems}] {  
      node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=6em]{\Large\bfseries{Single source}} [clockwise from=240]  
    child { node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em]{\large\bfseries{5 Samples}}[clockwise from=180]  
    child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=7em,text width=7em]    {\large\bfseries{LR Check}} }}  
    child { node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em]{\large\bfseries{7 Samples}}[clockwise from=180]  
    child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=7em,text width=7em]   {\large\bfseries{DNA Conc.}} }}  
        child { node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em]  {\large\bfseries{7 Samples}} [clockwise from=180]  
          child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=7em,text width=7em]   {\large\bfseries{Saturation}} }}
        child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=6em]{\Large\bfseries{94 Samples}} [clockwise from=135]
          child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em] {\large\bfseries{Stutter Ratio}} }  
child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=6em]   {\large\bfseries{Variances}} }}}
    child [concept color=orange, nodes={editors}] {
      node {STRmix} };  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't use A4 paper.

Comment: Can I make it work on a landscape A4paper?

Comment: If you use A4 paper, you can use A4 paper in portrait or landscape.

Comment: Treat it like any other box and place \vspace*{\fill} above and below it.  There is also the coordinate (current page.center) available when using [remember picture,overlay], which you could use as your starting coordinate.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please complete the code with your comments? @john-kormylo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the picture is too big to fit into the text area, and part of the problem is that the starting node is not at the center of the image.  (Standalone and geometry are incompatible, but since you wanted it on A4 paper, it doesn't matter.)

My solution was to put the mindmap into a savebox, then run tikz a second time to center the box in the page.  (Note: you need to run it twice.)

```
% Mindmap  
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz  
% https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook  
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}  
\usepackage{metalogo}  
%\usepackage{dtklogos}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}% no room for page number
\savebox{\tempbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path [  
    mindmap,  
    text = white, align=flush center,  
    level 1 concept/.append style =  
      {font=\large\bfseries, sibling angle=90},
    level 2 concept/.append style =
      {font=\normalsize\bfseries, level distance = 3.5cm, sibling angle=55},
    level 3 concept/.append style =  
      {font=\small\bfseries, level distance = 3.5cm, sibling angle=60},  
    tex/.style     = {concept, ball color=black,  
      font=\huge\bfseries},  
    engines/.style = {concept, ball color=green!50!black},  
    formats/.style = {concept, ball color=blue!50!black},  
    systems/.style = {concept, ball color=red!80!black},  
    editors/.style = {concept, ball color=orange!90!black}  
  ]  
  node [tex] {Samples} [clockwise from=0]  
    child[concept color=green!50!black, nodes={engines}] {  
      node {Mixtures} [clockwise from=750]  
        child { node {Series 1}}  
        child { node {Series 2} }  
       % child { node {\XeTeX} }  
        %child { node {Lua\TeX} }  
}  
    child [concept color=blue, nodes={formats}] {  
      node {Case Types} [clockwise from=300]  
        child { node {\LaTeX} }  
        child { node {Con\TeX t} }}  
    child [concept color=red, nodes={systems}] {  
      node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=6em]{\Large\bfseries{Single source}} [clockwise from=240]  
    child { node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em]{\large\bfseries{5 Samples}}[clockwise from=180]  
    child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=7em,text width=7em]    {\large\bfseries{LR Check}} }}  
    child { node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em]{\large\bfseries{7 Samples}}[clockwise from=180]  
    child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=7em,text width=7em]   {\large\bfseries{DNA Conc.}} }}  
        child { node [circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em]  {\large\bfseries{7 Samples}} [clockwise from=180]  
          child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=7em,text width=7em]   {\large\bfseries{Saturation}} }}
        child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=6em]{\Large\bfseries{94 Samples}} [clockwise from=135]
          child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=5em] {\large\bfseries{Stutter Ratio}} }  
child { node[circle,draw,minimum size=6em,text width=6em]   {\large\bfseries{Variances}} }}}
    child [concept color=orange, nodes={editors}] {
      node {STRmix} };  
\end{tikzpicture}}% create box
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {\usebox{\tempbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]